# rpm_build modifying sh files

Tags: rpmbuild

When I run rpm_build, it changes the first line of sh files from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/usr/bin/sh` - any idea what might cause this?

I observe this change whether I install the rpm or extract the files using cpio.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you building for? That distribution might be in the process of migrating to having all the standard commands in `/usr/bin` and having `/bin` contain only compatibility symlinks - and `rpmbuild` could be anticipating that.

Comment: From this I take it that I should build the rpm with the same distribution that I intend on running it on. Rookie mistake! Thanks :)

Comment: Can confirm that using the same distribution for building and installing solved this problem. Thanks again!